# Pasar datos de un activity a otro, pero que no estén unidos

Tags: android, android-studio

para explicarlo mejor, tengo 3 activities, A - B - C

Por ejemplo, A guarda un ID y se lo quiere pasar a C, pero antes de llegar a éste necesita pasar primero por B.

Nota: No quiero jalar el valor de A a B y de B a C, quiero que solo de A pase a C.

He buscado formas, pero lamentablemente no las encuentro.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si de A quieres pasar a C envía los datos con intent y a su vez guardalos en SharedPreferences para que B pueda leerlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el problema es que no se puede asegurar la existencia de un Activity desde otro Activity por lo que aunque logres acceder al Activity C desde el Activity A ese Activity podria no existir y causar errores, lo mismo al revez.

Si no queres arrastrar datos de activity en activity, podrias guardar los datos en la `sharedPreference` y luego leerlos en el activity que los necesite.

Asi guardas los datos en el Activity A por ejemplo

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MIS_PREFERENCIAS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("id", id);
editor.apply();
```

Asi los lees desde el Activity C

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MIS_PREFERENCIAS, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String idGuardado = prefs.getString("id", null);
```

Asegurate de validar que el idGuardado no sea null para evitar null pointer exceptions.

De esta forma no tenes que andar usando singletons ni variables globales, ademas que el dato queda guardado para posteriores ejecuciones incluso si la app se cierra.

Comment: Tienes razón, no lo había visto de esa forma, ahora lo tengo más claro. Muchas gracias, utilicé tu código y salió lo que quería :)